# Why ERROR iMacros convert to JavaScript (Result + Encoding)

Tags: javascript, imacros

i have problem in .js iMacros, bellow i explain.

.js file looks like:

```
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE \"start number.txt\"" + "\n";
```

and then encoding using base64:

```
macro +=  base64.enc("SET !DATASOURCE \"start number.txt\"") + "\n";
```

and then javascript result + encoding will be look like this:

```
macro +=  base64.dec("U0VUICFEQVRBU09VUkNFIFwic3RhcnQgbnVtYmVyLnR4dFwi") + "\n";
```

the problem is on javascript result + encoding when this script run by iMacros will get error, like this:

```
wrong format of SET command, line 11 (Error code: -910)
```

what's wrong? that "javasript result + encoding" in line-106 but why notification on line-11 ??? What?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: on line 1 - 94 is pure base64 code. If string --> SET !DATASOURCE "start number.txt" <-- iMacros .js cannot run. You know that iMacros run javascript must use quotes cause the style is onlye like this --> macro +=

Comment: [link](https://xs-sol.com/imacros-java-script-converter/) i use this tool to convert .iim to .js  -- my .iim file look like this --> **SET !DATASOURCE "start number.txt""** then by using that tool will be **macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE \"start number.txt\"" + "\n";** as .js absolutly.

Comment: actualy @JaromandaX i'm newbie in iMacros and .js and this is my first time must use .iim as .js and must encode then encrypt. Is any other better tools then [this one](https://xs-sol.com/imacros-java-script-converter/) ? please let me know and how to do this _(must use .iim as .js and must encode then encrypt)_ better as you a programmer :) Thanks